# InputRichText to display output

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, icefaces

I want inputRichText to display the output from the database which it was inputted earlier. The reason is the user get chance to input and display the data in same page. After inputting the data he can save it and retrieve it in the same inputRichText. Can you let me know if this work by in built or should i customize the js code? If so i would appreciate if someone have the js scripts. Also alternate idea are appreciated too. Right now i am using Icefaces component for inputRichText.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `value` attribute to set the content of inputRichText as string, also can use binding with the backing bean component of type `InputRichText`, but previous is more preferable way.

You can re-use the same object used for persisting data, to display the content later. It will be having the value fetched from the database & the same will be displayed as text. You have to initialize the string before displaying the page.